# How do I make content start after a background image (responsive)?

Tags: css

I have no idea how to fix this. I've included a picture of the site.
This only happens on larger screen monitors, for some reason. On my 14" laptop, its' fine. Anyway, is there any way to ensure that content starts underneath a background image? And not overlap it, as shown.

Thanks so much for any help.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6PbUr.jpg

Comment: If you put the code or the link to your site will help a lot!!!

Comment: Oh sorry! The site is theidlecritic.co.uk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it's complicated to work with css relativization when your main image of the site (the takes nearly all the screen) is into background or other rules that don't fill the rest of the elements. The best that you can do is to relativize body.home margin-top with percentages, but I highly recommend that you put that image inside a div container with width 100% and background-size cover and start to work towards that. Any other solution will be hacks and lacks of good practices, because if you want (and one day you will) change de background-image, all your elements will need a new proper location, obliging you to change css every time.

Comment: Thanks so much... just have to figure out how to do that lol :(

Comment: Put that background in a div, name a class for that div, put online and comments here, I'll help you.

Comment: Wow, when I add div to the line it makes the background crazy! (online now)

I don't want to waste your time :) I'm self taught so I'm still trying to figure everything out. Thanks so much for your reply. Very helpful, should make things easier in the future.

Comment: I'll try to help you, dont mind. Look, first of all, you repeated body.home div two times in the css (line 277 and line 85). Other thing: don't put everything inside the container of background, the div with the background will remain empty, remember, you want him detached, calling the user attention. Go changing and putting online, i'm here :)